# unable to compile Maven ,not creating testng file & throws [ERROR]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: apache, maven

I am getting this error while executing maven trying to fix this code for 5 days non of the solution working

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.**apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1**:test
>   (default-test) on project com.learn.selenium: Execution default-test
>   of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   failed: There was an error in the forked process
>       [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
>       [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>       [ERROR] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>       [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
>       [ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
>       [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
>       [ERROR] ... 7 more
>       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Answer (score 0):

Where is pom.xml?

Ok,fine

solve it using -U option along with mvn command as

```
   mvn clean install -U
```

hope it helps.